# UIToolbar doesn't show again in view when dismissing keyboard in Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uitoolbar, uitextfielddelegate, inputaccessoryview

I have an UIToolbar containing a UITextField. I want to show the toolbar above the keyboard and then display it again when I finish editing inside the textfield.

The issue is that it is working when selecting the textfield. However, the toolbar is disappearing from the view when hiding the keyboard. 
What should be done to redisplay it again to my view?

My Swift code is:
Add UITextFieldDelegate

```
class ATCChatThreadViewController: MessagesViewController, MessagesDataSource, MessageInputBarDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

Create ToolBar is as below

```
 func createToolbar(){

        //Fixed space
        let fixed = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.fixedSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        fixed.width = 10

        //Camera
        //let img = UIImage(named: "camera-filled-icon")!.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        let img = UIImage.localImage("camera-filled-icon", template: true)
        let iconSize = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
        let iconButton = UIButton(frame: iconSize)
        iconButton.setTitleColor(uiConfig.primaryColor, for: .normal)
        iconButton.setBackgroundImage(img, for: .normal)
        let cameraItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: iconButton)
        cameraItem.tintColor = uiConfig.primaryColor
        iconButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cameraButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

        //TextField true
        textFieldChat = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,(self.view.frame.size.width - 100) ,30))
        textFieldChat.tintColor = uiConfig.primaryColor
        textFieldChat.textColor = uiConfig.inputTextViewTextColor
        textFieldChat.backgroundColor = uiConfig.inputTextViewBgColor
        textFieldChat.layer.cornerRadius = 14.0
        textFieldChat.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        textFieldChat.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
        textFieldChat.delegate = self
        textFieldChat.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Start typing...".localized(), attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: uiConfig.inputPlaceholderTextColor])

        let paddingView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 20))
        textFieldChat.leftView = paddingView
        textFieldChat.leftViewMode = .always
        let textFieldButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: textFieldChat)

        //Fixed space
        let fixedTwo = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.fixedSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        fixedTwo.width = 10

        //Send Button
        let imgSend = UIImage.localImage("share-icon", template: true)
        let iconSendSize = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
        let sendButton = UIButton(frame: iconSendSize)
        sendButton.setTitleColor(uiConfig.primaryColor, for: .normal)
        sendButton.setBackgroundImage(imgSend, for: .normal)
        let sendItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: sendButton)
        sendItem
            .tintColor = uiConfig.primaryColor
        sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendBtnPressedWith), for: .touchUpInside)

        //Flexible Space
        //        let flexible = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        let flexible = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.fixedSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        flexible.width = 10

        //Toolbar
        var bottomsafeAreaHeight: CGFloat?
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            bottomsafeAreaHeight = UIApplication.shared.windows.first{$0.isKeyWindow }?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            bottomsafeAreaHeight = bottomLayoutGuide.length
            bottomsafeAreaHeight = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.bottomLayoutGuide.length ?? 0
        }

        toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0,(self.view.frame.size.height - 116 - (bottomsafeAreaHeight ?? 0)),view.frame.width,50))
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.f5f5f5ColorBg()
        toolbar.isTranslucent = false
        toolbar.tintColor = uiConfig.primaryColor
        toolbar.items = [fixed, cameraItem, fixed, textFieldButton,fixedTwo, sendItem,flexible]
        view.addSubview(toolbar)
    }



   // MARK: - UITextFieldDelegate

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textFieldChat.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    return true
}
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
     view.addSubview(toolbar)
     self.toolbar.isHidden = false
     return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if only chat etxfield is using toolbar then replace line:

```
view.addSubview(toolbar)
```

with

```
textFieldChat.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
```

remove both methods `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` and `textFieldShouldEndEditing`

Comment: Hi @Van, if I remove the line view.addSubview(toolbar), then nothing will be shown since the 3 items(camera, textfield and send) are inside the uitoolbar. I am using uitabbar and i need them to appear above the tab bar by default and to move with the keyboard when the textfield begin editing.